# Divide function returns wrong value

Tags: c++

I have a function which will supposedly check if there's an indices `i` such that it is equal to `v[i]`. `V` is a strictly ascending ordered vector. It needs to be done in `O(logn)` and I thought about divide. I was never really familiar with recursion. I wrote this code and I don't really know why it won't work. Something's missing. If I put `cout << mid` instead of return it will show the right value, but I guess that's not the proper way to do it, frankly. In this stage the mid value returned is 7, and I don't know why.

Here's the code.

```
int customDivide(vector <int>& v, int left, int right)
{
    if(left <= right)
    {
        int mid = (left+right)/2;
        if(mid == v[mid]){
            //cout<<mid<<" ";
            return mid;
        }
    customDivide(v,left,mid-1);
    customDivide(v,mid+1,right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your function doesn't return on most path.

Comment: Is `v` a sorted vector?

Comment: not all your paths return value -> UB.

Comment: When `left == right` you should probably return a result; so this should be your 1st test,

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, it is.

Comment: It seems like you may be under the impression that `return` propagates the value through the entire callstack. This function will only work when `mid == v[mid]` on the first try.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes, I may be, could you please ellaborate why it wouldn't? :( Can't really seem to figure it out.

Comment: If the first call to `customDivide` doesn't hit the `return`, it will instead reach the end of the function without returning. It doesn't matter what *other* calls (including recursive calls) to `customDivide` do, the result of *this* call depends only the `return` statement encountered during *this* execution of the function.

Comment: You don't have to do the recursion on both sides.

Comment: @RichardCritten That's not exactly right, `left == right`, doesn't necessarily mean that `left == v[left]`.

Comment: Always enable compiler warnings.

Comment: Besides other errors, you are not taking advantage of the sorted nature of the vector. The code above will traverse *all* elements of the vector, making it `O(n)` instead of `O(log n)`. You need to reject at least one branch every time.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Being sorted doesn't really help me that much, I don't know how to reject a part of a vector since I'll need to check if an indices is equal to the value at that indices which doesn't imply that I should look in the left or right of the vector.

Comment: @Jarod42 this isn't absolutely true, if the logic of the program make it so that the function always hit a return statement, your function has defined behavior even if an other path has no return.

Comment: With **strictly** increasing vector, with `v[42] = 50`, for any positive number `i`, `v[42 + i] > 50 + i > 42 + i`.

Comment: @Tyker: `s/not all your paths/not all your executed paths/` :-) indeed, not clear enough.

Comment: @Jarod42 You're right about that, didn't know why I hadn't that in mind already...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems exist here, and I will attempt to explain them with an analogy of finding a lost dog in your neighborhood.

1. You are not returning a value from the function, unless you found the correct element immediately. You promise to return a value (an `int`) but you don't always do it.

   This is like promising to send the dog owner a letter to indicate where their lost dog can be found. You check your garden and if you find the dog, you send a letter - that works. If you didn't find the dog, you go to your neighbors and have them promise to send you a letter if they find the dog, using the same method as you did (recursion). The problem is that in this case **you are not reading or forwarding their letters** (the return values from your two recursive function calls at the end) - **you are just throwing these letters away**. Worse, you are not actually sending back the letter to the guy looking for his dog if you didn't find it yourself (no `return` after the calls). Your code seems to assume that the neighbors will automatically send the letter to the dog owner - that is not how `return` works, it just sends the letter to the previous person in the chain (in code terms, the *call stack*), so if that person throws it into the trash right away, the system won't work.
2. You cannot get O(log(n)) performance if you unconditionally recurse to both sides.

   If you **always ask all your neighbors** (and they ask all of theirs), you will have literally every person in the neighborhood looking for the dog. That's O(n). You must identify which of your two neighbors should look for the dog (e.g. by looking at the trail the dog left) and **only ask that one**. This way you halve the number of people that might have to search for the dog at each step, giving you O(log(n)) performance.

   This "trail" is something you need to know beforehand. In your case, it is not clear what that could be - the dog could be anywhere (all elements could have random values) and you have no idea where to go looking. You need to figure out this detail of the task to get to your O(log(n)) time. It could be that vector elements are strictly increasing (see @Jarod42's comment), i.e. there are no duplicate elements and each one is larger than the previous one. In that case you can decide that only one of the two remaining halves can possibly contain what you are looking for, thus recursing there.

*(Yes I know, the analogy breaks down unless your neighborhood is shaped like a binary tree with you at the top and a non-reciprocal definition of "neighbors".)*

Answer (score 1):

As a result of all the help involved here, I finally understood what the problem was.

- 1st of all - It didn't take advantage of the fact that the vector was strictly sorted.
- 2nd - Every function in the stack returns something now.

```
int customDivide(vector <int>& v, int left, int right)
{
    if(left <= right)
    {
        int mid = (left+right)/2;
        if(mid == v[mid])
            return mid;
        else if(v[mid] < mid)
            return customDivide(v,mid+1,right);
        else
            return customDivide(v,left, mid-1);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Thanks a lot for all your help!